# How can I stop cloudflare from redirecting a url on my site?

Tags: cloudflare

I have cloudflare redirect/cache all requests:

https://domain.no -> https://www.domain.no

Now, [apple requires](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/106872) that the applinks descriptor file (.well-known/apple-app-site-association) to NOT redirect with 301

real url should stay without "www." added: https://domain.no/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

I've tried adding full URI matches to Page rules, Rewrite rules, Cache rules…
all end up with

```
Connecting to domain.no…|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.domain.no/.well-known/apple-app-site-association [following]
```

What I'm looking for is a Rewrite, not a Redirect. Not sure if that's doable though?

Answer (score 0):

Got some help from @epic.network at Cloudflare community pointing me to the correct place:

- I couldn't find any redirect setup in Cloudflare itself, which was puzzling.
- Turns out the *origin server* was setup to redirect domain.no to [www.domain.no](http://www.domain.no) actually

[image: Add www feature]

From what I can see from history, this www setting has something to do with a wordpress bug/feature

But we use next instead of wordpress now, and I don’t like www. anyway so it’s definitely gone from everywhere

So request flow was like this, cloudflare just did its caching job:

```
GET domain.no → cloudflare → origin server → 301 www.
GET www.domain.no → cloudflare → origin server → proper response
```

Keywords are Cloudflare assetlinks apple .well-known apple-app-site-association redirect and Dreamhost